# Change UIButton for Specific cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Having issues updating uibutton in specific uitableviewcell. When I change the button color it updates every button in uitableview. Attached my code below:

```
  PFObject *post = [self.objectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.likeBtn.layer.cornerRadius    = 5.0f;

    //To access button methods
    [cell.likeBtn    setTag:indexPath.section];


    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary
                                       dictionaryWithDictionary:[[TMMemoryCache sharedCache] objectForKey:post.objectId]];


    BOOL likedByCurrentUser = [[attributes objectForKey:@"likedByCurrentUser"] boolValue];

    if (likedByCurrentUser) {

        cell.likeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatRedColor];
        [cell.likeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.likeBtn setTitle:@"Liked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{

        //NSLog(@"Did not like %@", post.objectId);
        cell.likeBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatBlueColor];
        [cell.likeBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.likeBtn setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

is their a better way to update uibutton in just one specific cell?

Comment: where have you put this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do what you want, depending on how the updated information comes in:

1. When configuring the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. Let the cell manage its own contents.

More often than not, #1 is the way to go. When new information comes into your `UITableViewController`, do 1 of the following:

1. Call `reloadData` to force a refresh of the entire table.
2. Figure out which cells need to be updated and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing in the correct index path values.

In either of those scenarios, you'll set up the button correctly somewhere in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Generally, I create my `UITableViewCell` subclasses to accept an object and configure themselves with the data in that object. That way, there's less code in my `UITableViewController` that deals with cell configuration.

A typical implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"item" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureForItem:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Each of your `UITableViewCell` instances will have their own button that will be configured by the data passed by the object in `self.dataSource[indexPath.row]`. That way, as cells are recycled, the button isn't just passed around, but a new one is recycled and configured each time a new cell is needed.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, without seeing more of your code I would say your issue is with your use of indexPath.section instead of indexPath.row

If you have multiple buttons per section then they will all be covered by this code.